# Como pesquisa por qualquer termo retirando espaços, traços e pontos com LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma dificuldade para alterar uma pesquisa que tenho, hoje ao pesquisar um código que tenha, por exemplo essa máscara `A 901.325.0744` a busca faz correta pois o código está cadastrado dessa forma e a busca agora é feita sem o ponto, traço e espaço, mas como posso  concatenar o `LIKE` nessa minha query fazendo com que a busca encontre o produto por qualquer termo, já tentei algumas alternativas e não deu certo.

O que tenho é isso, o meu SQL inicial:

```
// PESQUISA INICIAL
$sql = "   
SELECT 
      produtos.codigo,
      produtos.nome,
      produtos.lancamento,
      produtos.id_categoria,
      produtos.id_produto,
      produtos.data_inicial,
      produtos.data_expiracao                             
    FROM
      `produtos`      
    WHERE
      (produtos.id_idioma = '".$_SESSION['idioma']."') AND
      (produtos.`status` = 1)
  ";
```

A `query` dinâmica que criei para ir concatenando as buscas:

```
$sqla = " AND REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(codigo_original,'.',''),'-',''),' ','')  = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('".$pesquisa."','.',''),'-',''),' ','') OR
              REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(codigo_original1,'.',''),'-',''),' ','') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('".$pesquisa."','.',''),'-',''),' ','') OR
              REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(codigo_original2,'.',''),'-',''),' ','') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('".$pesquisa."','.',''),'-',''),' ','') OR
              REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(codigo_original3,'.',''),'-',''),' ','') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('".$pesquisa."','.',''),'-',''),' ','')";
```

A busca com os campos concatenados:

```
if ($sqla != "") {
    $sql = $sql . $sqla . $ordenacao; 
} else {
    $sql = $sql . $ordenacao;
}
```

Alguns dados da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como exemplo, gostaria que ao usuário pesquisar `411`, termo que faz parte da coluna codigo_original e codigo_original1 fosse exibido esses registros no resultado da pesquisa.,

Comment: Consegue fornecer exemplos de seus dados para que possamos dar uma resposta funcional?

Comment: Olá @Sorack o que exatamente precisa?

Comment: Coloca umas 3 linhas com dados da sua tabela e o termo que você está pesquisando que retornaria uma delas. Assim posso sugerir as substituições ou até uma forma alternativa de resolver seu problema

Comment: No seu exemplo os outros 2 registros não seriam mostrados?

Comment: Sim, seriam mostrados no resultado da busca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira sugestão que dou é que você crie uma função para remover caracteres especiais do texto:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION remover_especiais(texto VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
 DECLARE resultado VARCHAR(20);
 
 SET resultado = REPLACE(texto, '.', '');
 SET resultado = REPLACE(resultado, '-', '');
 SET resultado = REPLACE(resultado, ' ', '');
  
 RETURN resultado;
END
```

Depois disso, para utilizar no `PHP` basta realizar a chamada da seguinte forma:

```
$sqla = " AND remover_especiais(codigo_original) LIKE CONCAT('%', remover_especiais('".$pesquisa."'), '%') OR
              remover_especiais(codigo_original1) LIKE CONCAT('%', remover_especiais('".$pesquisa."'), '%') OR
              remover_especiais(codigo_original2) LIKE CONCAT('%', remover_especiais('".$pesquisa."'), '%') OR
              remover_especiais(codigo_original3) LIKE CONCAT('%', remover_especiais('".$pesquisa."'), '%')";
```

Você pode ver a `query` em funcionamento no [**DB Fiddle**.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMZoAtNNGYzvZgT4sHbTwx/0)

---

> **[`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**
>
> For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the strings next to each other.

Em tradução livre:

> Para strings destacadas, concatenção pode ser realizada colocando as strings uma após a outra.

Comment: Me ajuda ai, onde e como uso essa função, onde declaro para remover caracteres?

Comment: É só executá-la no seu banco. A chamada é feita como no `WHERE` que dei de exemplo. Fiz mais um questionamento na sua pergunta, dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: Para os novos produtos cadastrados devo executar essa função?

Comment: @adventistapr só precisa executá-la na busca. Adicionei um exemplo ao DB-Fiddle e inclui o link na minha resposta.

Comment: me perdoe a minha ignorância, mas ainda não entendi como é feita a execução dessa função  na busca, esse código deve ser inserido no meu SQL?

Comment: @adventistapr a criação da função sim. A chamada é feita no WHERE como no exemplo

Comment: @adventistapr conseguiu?

Comment: Olá @Sorack, sim, foi uma super dica, nunca tinha feito uma função como essa, ficou show.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que a melhor forma de se fazer isso é remover os espaços e pontos no backend antes de submeter o termo para a consulta SQL. E na consulta, você faz o mesmo com o campo, removendo os espaços e os pontos. Fazendo as devidas adaptações para o seu exemplo, seria assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM `sua_tabela`
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(nome_do_campo,' ',''),'.','') = '$pesquisa_formatada'
```

Onde a variável `$pesquisa_formatada` é o termo pesquisado sem os espaços e pontos.

Dessa forma, não importa se o usuário digitou `A 901.325.0744` ou `A901.325.0744` ou `A9013250744` a consulta vai sempre funcionar.

Comment: Vou testar a sua dica, valeu @AlexandrePaiva.

Comment: Avisa aí caso tenha dado certo ou se ainda tiver alguma dúvida.

Comment: Olá @AlexandrePaiva, valeu pelo post, mas já estava fazendo isso.

Answer (score 2):

Meu caro, tenta dessa forma, caso não funcione me avise para buscar outra solução e se atende aos caracteres, se estão realmente em utf8

```
$palavras = explode(' ', $pesquisa);
$sqla = "";
foreach($palavras as $indice => $valor){
        $sqla .= " AND (`codigo_original` LIKE '%".$valor."%') OR
        (`codigo_original1` LIKE '%".$valor."%') OR
        (`codigo_original2` LIKE '%".$valor."%') OR
        (`codigo_original3` LIKE '%".$valor."%')";
    }
```

Comment: Opa, vou testar também, valeu @JoaoPauloAraujo